# BufferUnderflowException when making a font

Tags: java, fonts

I am trying to create a custom font for use in my program and think I have the code configured correctly.  However, I am getting BufferUnderflowException when I try to run it.

I suspect that it might be caused by java not reading the .ttf in quite the same way it was created, but that is about as far as my understanding goes.  If anyone has some insight, I would appreciate it.

Edit:

I realized it might be helpful to see the error:

```
    java.awt.FontFormatException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.createFont2D(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)

 try {
            final InputStream stream = 
                            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("fonts\\b.ttf"));
            myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream);
            myFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20f);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
                            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream));           

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I see a single try, with five code calls, and two catches, so I assume you've already isolated which line is throwing the error but forgot to tell us: please update your question with that information. If you haven't: you're on the hook to [do that, first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Put try/catch around your calls to find out which one is breaking, then with that new knowledge, do some searching to see if anyone already ran into that more specific problem, and then if you can't find anything, you have a much better question to ask on SO.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks to your input.  it was throwing an error on the last line of the try statement, when I tried to register the font.  I decided to just paste in the font (myFont) instead of Font.createFont...   This resolved the error and the font now works!!!  Thanks again.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to the question and mark it as resolved. It'll help others.